# GridView paging on custom collecton

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am using paging on a `GridView` that is tied to a `List<Employee>`. But this code does not work. What is the correct way? I am not using an `ObjectDataSource`.

```
protected void myGV_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    List<Employee> p = ReturnEmplColl();
    GridView1.DataSource = p.Paging(1, e.NewPageIndex);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void myGV_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Employee> p = ReturnEmplColl();
        GridView1.DataSource = p;
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by paging like this:

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
GridView1.DataSource = ReturnEmplColl();
```